# Feedback-linearization of a pendulum around $\delta_1\neq 0$

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, linearization

In Non Linear Control Theory (Khalil) it is proposed the stabilization of the pendulum equation by feedback linearization.
In particular let $\delta_1\neq 0$ we want by $u=u_{SS}+u_\delta$ to stabilize the pendulum around this equilibrium point.
First of all it is opportune to find out $u_{SS}$ such that the system with this input has at the origin an equilibrium point and then we will design $u_\delta$ in order to stabilize the transformed system around the origin. So:
if the pendulum equation is given by:
$\begin{cases}
\dot x_1=x_2\\
\dot x_2=-bx_2-\sin{x_1}+cu
\end{cases}$
I have thought (and it is confirmed by the book) that it is necessary a transformation like this:
$\begin{cases}
 z_1=x_1-\delta_1\\
z_2=x_2
\end{cases}$
from which then the resulting dynamic is:
$\begin{cases}
\dot z_1=z_2\\
\dot z_2=-bz_2-\sin{(z_1+\delta_1)}+cu
\end{cases}$
In order to obtain at the origin an equilibrium point I should have $0=-\sin{\delta_1}+cu$ and so $u_{SS}=\frac{\sin{\delta_1}}{c}$.
In another example of the same pendulum equation it is said:
a linearizing-stabilizing feeedback control is given by: $u=\frac{\sin{(z_1+\delta_1)}}{c}+u_\delta$.
So my question is:  which one of the two cited $u_{SS}$ is correct? ($u=\frac{\sin{(z_1+\delta_1)}}{c}$ or $u=\frac{\sin{\delta_1}}{c}$?)

Comment: @AVK Maybe it can be said that really the two $u_{SS}$ are equal, since the second cited in effect at the origin is equal to the previous one?

Comment: H.Khalil denotes the control value at the equilibrium point as $u_{ss}$. So $u_{ss}$ can't be equal to $\frac{\sin{(z_1+\delta_1)}}{c}$. It must be a constant.